# Flutter, having trouble sending a post form-data request using MultipartRequest

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies, multipartform-data

How are you?

I'm working on a personal project trying to use Flutter to send an image + other information to my web server using the post request in form-data format. Here is an example in Postman:

[image]

Here is my flutter code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class ConfirmationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final XFile? pictureFile;
  final String uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/analyze';
  final Position? position;
  const ConfirmationScreen({this.pictureFile, this.position, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ConfirmationScreen> createState() => _ConfirmationScreenState();
}

class _ConfirmationScreenState extends State<ConfirmationScreen> {
  
  Future<void> uploadImage ()async{

    var stream  = http.ByteStream(widget.pictureFile!.openRead());
    stream.cast();

    var length = await widget.pictureFile!.length();

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/analyze');

    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

    request.fields['taken_at'] = "18/09/19 01:55:19" ;
    request.fields['latitude'] = widget.position!.latitude.toString();
    request.fields['longitude'] = widget.position!.longitude.toString();
    request.fields['id_camera'] = "2" ;
    request.fields['camera_type'] = "phone" ;
    request.fields['false_alarm'] = '0' ;

    var multiport = http.MultipartFile(
        'file',
        stream,
        length);

    request.files.add(multiport);

    await request.send() ;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Confirmation")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.file(File(widget.pictureFile!.path)),
          Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.red, 
                textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                ),
              onPressed: (){}, 
              child: const Text("BACK"),),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0,0,0,0)),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.green,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                ),
              // Image.file(File(widget.pictureFile!.path))
              onPressed: () async {
                uploadImage();
              }, 
              child: const Text("SEND"))
          ],
          ),
          Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), 
          child: Text(
            style: const TextStyle(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              widget.position!.latitude.toString()
              )
              ),
          Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), 
          child: Text(
            style: const TextStyle(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              widget.position!.longitude.toString()
              )
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's a simple screen. I'm only displaying the image and 2 buttons. One is to send the data to the web server and the other one is to go back.

However, I'm getting this error when pressing the "send" button:

```
E/flutter (30566): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused
E/flutter (30566): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (30566): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30566): #1      BaseRequest.send (package:http/src/base_request.dart:133:22)
```

If anyone can lend me a hand it would be much appreciated. Have a nice day!

Comment: Are you trying it on a physical device or a simulator

Comment: I'm trying on a physical device

Answer (score 0):

connect your physical device and your host to the same wifi network and change your URL on this line to the IP Address of your host..

```
var uri = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/analyze');
```

to find the IP Address of your host, open command prompt (for windows) or terminal (for mac or linux) and type `ipconfig` and look for the ipv4 address and replace the `127.0.0.1` with the `IP Address` and it will work.

Comment: I tried using my ipv4 address and also using the emulator with 127.0.0.1 but I still get the same error: E/flutter (16035): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused
E/flutter (16035): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (16035): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16035): #1      BaseRequest.send (package:http/src/base_request.dart:133:22)
E/flutter (16035): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16035): #2      _ConfirmationScreenState.uploadImage (package:stopfire/confirmation_screen.dart:47:5)

Comment: check if your backend has no issues with CORS and make sure to check if your backend is giving you access with HTTP or HTTPS.. also dont use 127.0.0.1 if you are accessing it from another device.. 127.0.0.1 means localhost

Comment: I only used 127.0.0.1 with the emulator. I used ipv4 of my machine for the device